# "come a long way" [V+OBJ/COMP/ADJUNCT]?

Tags: syntax, parts-of-speech, constituents, constituency, grammatical-category

Can someone tell me

i) in terms of constituent tree structure, if *a long way* is a complement as opposed to an adjunct

ii) in terms of thematic roles, whether *a long way* takes on the role of location or is there such a role as "distance"?

iii) in terms of syntactic category, is the ostensible NP functioning as an adverbial phrase?

iv) in the sentence *She has come a long way*, is the thematic role of the subject theme/experiencer/agent?

My appreciation for your time and help!!

Comment: I always thought that "come a long way" was an idiomatic phrasal verb.

Comment: Measure phrases with verbs of motion are very common: _Go ten miles, Move three blocks, Come across the room,_ etc. What's the problem?